# I dont know how to do order by in linkq with multiple table

Tags: linq

I have two tables. one is `product` table and another table having `StockQuantity` based on the warehouse. now I need the product having more then 10 quantity. now please help me to solve this issue

```
 query = query.Where(product =>
(product.UseMultipleWarehouses ? product.ProductWarehouseInventory.Sum(pwi => pwi.StockQuantity - pwi.ReservedQuantity)
: product.StockQuantity) > searchQty
```

now i need to do sorting also.but dont know how to do this with linq query?

Comment: I think you have misplaced a right parenthesis before group by. It should be after end of having clause

Comment: You select from pwi, but group by a p column. Switch to [pwi].ProductId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your query:

- As mentioned by apomene, paranthesis are not at right place. Please try below query:

> ```
> select * from Product p
>         where p.Id != 0
>         AND  
>         (
>             (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND p.StockQuantity = 10)
>             OR
>             (p.UseMultipleWarehouses != 0 AND
>                 EXISTS (SELECT pwi.Id FROM ProductWarehouseInventory [pwi]
>                 WHERE ([pwi].ProductId = p.Id) --) commented here
>                 GROUP BY p.Id
>                 HAVING (SUM([pwi].StockQuantity) - SUM([pwi].ReservedQuantity)) = 10
>               ) -- added here
>         )
>         ) -- This one was also missing - closing paranthesis for AND
> ```

- After fixing the error you will get another error because pwi.Id is not part of group by. So please try (notice the count ) something like below:

**UPDATED Query and Added DB Fiddler details:**

```
select * from Product p
    where p.Id != 0
    AND  
    (
        (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND p.StockQuantity = 10)
        OR
        (p.UseMultipleWarehouses != 0 AND
            EXISTS (SELECT pwi.ProductId --CASE WHEN count([pwi].ProductId) > 0 THEN count([pwi].ProductId) ELSE NULL END  FROM ProductWarehouseInventory [pwi]
            WHERE ([pwi].ProductId = p.Id) --) commented here
            GROUP BY [pwi].ProductId --p.Id
            HAVING (SUM([pwi].StockQuantity) - SUM([pwi].ReservedQuantity)) = 10
          ) -- added here
        )
    )
```

Here is [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=28e3eb011fa9a34d8b8ad680fa9ddffa).

Please note the main intention of creating fiddler is correcting the query. Since I don't know the actual data, I just inserted some dummy data so, try with your real data and post us your observations.

Comment: @SangeetShah I have update the query. could you try now.

Comment: @SangeetShah I have updated the query and also added fildder. Please try now.

Answer (score 3):

Some issue with closing   )

try this way

```
select * 
from Product p
where p.Id != 0
AND  (
    (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND p.StockQuantity = 10)
    OR  ( 
      p.UseMultipleWarehouses != 0 
      AND EXISTS (
          SELECT pwi.Id 
          FROM ProductWarehouseInventory [pwi]
          INNER JOIN Product ON [pwi].ProductId = p.Id
          GROUP BY [pwi].Id 
          HAVING (SUM([pwi].StockQuantity) - SUM([pwi].ReservedQuantity)) = 10
      )
    )
)
```

added  join in inner  exist for scoping

Comment: As @jarlh's comment.  I do think you also need to fix `GROUP BY` clause from `GROUP BY p.Id` to `GROUP BY [pwi].ProductId`

Comment: sorry @scaisEdge but getting same error from this code

Comment: your query not throw but i didnt get any result

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax has a problem with parenthesis, So you can fix like this

```
SELECT*
FROM Product p
WHERE p.Id != 0
    AND
    (
        (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND p.StockQuantity = 10)
        OR
        (p.UseMultipleWarehouses != 0 AND
            EXISTS
            (   SELECT[pwi].ProductId FROM ProductWarehouseInventory[pwi]
                WHERE[pwi].ProductId = p.Id
                GROUP BY[pwi].ProductId
                HAVING( SUM([pwi].StockQuantity) - SUM([pwi].ReservedQuantity) = 10))
    ))
```

According to @jarlh's comment.  I do think you also need to fix `GROUP BY` clause from `GROUP BY p.Id` to `GROUP BY [pwi].ProductId`

Comment: error gone but result getting wrong.  My 10 quantity condition not applied

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Sangeet Shah

Comment: It's usually a good idea to give us your sample data with the corresponding result. Simply because it's hard for us to help you correct syntax without testing :)

Comment: this one is nopcommerce database tables.

Comment: Yes, you can create temp table to help us reproduce your problem.